# TURN server under proxy pass with Apache web server

Tags: apache, webrtc, turn

I am trying to my own coturn (TURN) server. I want it to run on port 443. I have Apache already running on that port. Can i use Apache proxy pass to run  TURN on port 3479, 53499 but still listening to port 443?
I am not sure how to go about this problem. Is my approach wrong?. If yes, whats the better approach

```
listening-port=3478 
alt-listening-port=3479
tls-listening-port=5349
alt-tls-listening-port=5350



#stening-port=80

#tls-listening-port=443

listening-ip=127.0.0.1



relay-ip=127.0.0.1
external-ip=*****
realm=explain.bookmane.in
server-name=explain.bookmane.in

lt-cred-mech
userdb=/etc/turnuserdb.conf
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If yes, it would be nice, if you could post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the latest version of COTURN, COTURN 4.5.2r3, recently released this year, and still marked as unstable, has just incorporated support for reverse proxy. I infer this from description I found in its config file: /etc/turnserver.conf
https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/examples/etc/turnserver.conf

This is what it says:

```
# Some network setups will require using a TCP reverse proxy in front
# of the STUN server. If the proxy port option is set a single listener
# is started on the given port that accepts connections using the
# haproxy proxy protocol v2.
# (https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt)
#
#tcp-proxy-port=5555"
```